# Is it possible to make a 220 VAC to 12 VDC, 5 A transformerless power supply?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, switch-mode-power-supply, inductor, transformerless

I need to make a power supply that takes 220 VAC and outputs 12 VDC and can handle 5 A.

Where I live there are no flyback transformers for sale and importing them is a big hassle.

I have some ideas but I don't know their limits and if they are viable or not.

1- Reactance (x-capacitor) based voltage divider.

2- After rectification I will use a homemade air core inductor and an op-amp with a voltage reference and a transistor to maintain 12 V on the inductor, or I can do the same with a capacitor.

3- Use high-current diodes in series until I reach 12 V and take the voltage from them, but I don't know if a resistor is viable as it needs to be paired with them to allow 5 A and drop almost 300 V (1500 W).

4- PWM with many stages to reach the desired output, but I don't know how to make the feedback. I might use PWM to reduce the voltage to maybe 20 VDC and then use an op-amp with a transistor to regulate the voltage to 12 V.

Until now I don't know which one is the best or which would even work for my application. Any other transformerless design that can handle high currents is appreciated as well.

Note: I will take care of in-rush current, output filtering, surges, and for the isolation the power supply will have an isolated connector so the contacts cannot be touched.

Edit 1 : I can't get my hands on ferrite or flyback transformers, my question is about transformerless design, if I could get my hands on flyback transformers I wouldn't have asked as I know with my limited knowledge that flyback is a superior solution, so instead of I couldn't get the transformers, how about "it tickles my curiosity to know transformerless limits and draw backs at high current "

Note : I don't think I will be building it after the great feedback I received, but I wonder what is wrong with the fourth option using pwm to get around 20v and then using op-amp to stabilize 12v with a transistor (as what a linear regulator do) ?

Comment: Can you simply buy a supply with a transformer in it? Instead of trying to buy a transformer, try to buy a power supply. For example, it might be designed for a laptop.

Comment: I guarantee that you can find or make a transformer-based power supply. Everything around you has a transformer in it. Those transformers come from somewhere.

Comment: What about using a plain old toroidal transformer? You should be able to find one of an appropriate output for 12V extra low voltage lighting, if nothing else.

Comment: If toroidal transformer can handle high current then it might be a good option although it is not available for sale as well, I think I can use aluminum core, I will need 5000 peices, I work in installing cameras and low voltage applications, and I asked my employer about the possibility to make the power supplies as there is an issue with the available currently and it keeps increasing in price, he offered that he will buy 5000 pieces if I was able to make it cheaper, that is why I can't buy a power supply for the transformer

Comment: If you make a transformerless power supply for a low voltage application in security, you'll end up killing someone. Not the best news for a company doing security, right? If you need 5000 of those, the best bet is just to buy them from China, from a reputable supplier like Mean-Well. It absolutely will be the cheapest - way cheaper than making anything yourself, even if your time was free. Power supply manufacturers have economies of scale that are not available directly to you. 5000 pieces is what they make every day, and more.

Comment: I know, but here there is an issue with importing and currently it is very hard to import, also customs are very high, I can confidentaly say that you will pay at least quadruple the price. Because of high inflation rates, and the EGP is constantly going down in value.

Comment: The thing is customs are quite high on full products, but very low on the parts itself so local manufacturing can compete, that's why I'm thinking this way

Comment: You must have a transformer to provide isolation between the mains and the low-voltage side. If you are producing these then you will be legally liable for their safety certification and if someone is injured or killed using one you may be held responsible. If you can't do it safely then just don't do it.

Comment: If customs are high on finished products and low on parts, there must be local power supply manufacturers taking advantage of this.

Comment: It's not difficult to make a regular mains voltage AC transformer for a linear DC supply. For 5000 pieces you can get E-I laminations punched or water/laser cut to your specs, and then all you need are bobbins and a coil winder. Find a similar transformer in electronics junk and take it apart to see how it's made. You can also buy ferrite cores and bobbins for a switching supply, but designing and building is a major engineering task.

Comment: If you can’t get ferrite transformers then how will you get the specialised mosfets, ics and diodes for your power supplies?  If importation is a challenge - get to know your country’s import/customs rules and find creative means to work them to your advantage. It could be the taxes in importing a kit of parts is more favourable than importing finished products. If so, negotiate with a psu supplier to sell you kits of parts. You assemble them locally. No design required from you. Note I’m not suggesting you break the law but rather to understand it and see if you can bend it to your needs.

Comment: Consider making mains frequency transformers. You may be able to source surplus products or make new ones with all local parts. A microwave oven transformer will supply enough libation material for 5 to 10 of what want.The copper wire an be reused but may not be enough and you would need additional insulation material. Cellphone power supplies coukbe operated in parallel with due care. Laminations should be able to be made locally for mains transformers. What electronic items are commonly scrapped?

Comment: Transformerlrss  supplies are a lethally bad safety hazard.

Comment: @Kartman it is not illegal to do what you said it reduces customs a bit because there is a law for it they reduce 10% customs on it, and actually that is what the market offers currently.

Comment: @ATCSVOL jelly bean chips and transistors are readily available may even be cheaper than what I could buy them at in China in a 5000 count because there are only a couple of importers and they do it at a crazy volume. 555, op-amps, logic gates, voltage regulators, irf family mosfets are really common as they import electronic parts for students and fixing electronics so the varaity is quite tight as students and technicians use really simple stuff, big manufacturers import there own parts if needed, but generally electronics manufacturering is really limited, maybe only multinational companies

Comment: In addition, with all honest respect, I don't think electronics stack are appropriate for political discussions, I'd love to talk about it as much as I can as I get real helpful ideas, but I don't want to cross the line of the purpose of this forum as this question might face many different hobbiests and there situation might be different than mine and I want it to be appropriate for the purpose of stack community to help many people as possible and add it to a database of questions that have no answer.

Comment: Can you purchase laptop power supplies where you live? They are typically about 20 V. Maybe you can just use a buck converter to convert the 20 V output to 12 V.

Comment: laptop power supplies are more expensive

Comment: Again. Unisolated mains input supplies will kill people. Especially in volume production.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a flyback transformer. Those are custom anyway, so you can't just "go out and buy one" pretty much anywhere in the world. You'd have to design one first, and then have it manufactured for you. And designing such a supply is not exactly trivial, since it's much harder to make it safe when designed by a novice - compared to a mains frequency transformer.

All you need is an old battery charger or CB radio power supply to get a usual 50Hz 220V to "12V" transformer. Battery chargers and CB radio supplies often have secondary windings rated at over 5A, so that's all you need.

You can also use one or two ATX power supplies to get 12V at 5A. I'm sure there's plenty of those in electronic junk that's available in just about any country.

A transformerless supply will not be galvanically isolated from mains, and if it were to fail, your 12V project will suddenly find itself fed from 220VAC. Not a good prospect.

> Is it possible to make a 220 VAC to 12 VDC, 5 A transformerless power supply?

Certainly. But that's the last thing you'd want to do. I've made such supplies in the past and they are ultra-compact - pretty much a very precise angle-controlled rectifier using a MOSFET. Mains goes through a bridge rectifier, a mosfet for phase control, a double comparator, a gate driver, a chunky bulk output capacitor. But there's absolutely no line isolation, and they dump lots of EMI into the mains. Only usable in very specific cirmcumstances - in that case those were for use in remote, inaccessible locations, with nobody nearby, so EMC was not a big concern.

Comment: Thanks your answer is very helpful, I can't use an atx supply or any other but I was wondering about phone charger's transformer to be used as they are very cheap, also I thought about making my own transformer, but I don't think it will be easy as there are no manufacturers that can do it, it will need to be handmade or I will need to make a machine that can make them in volume, in addition I have no experience designing them and no access to ferrite core

Comment: Also if you may what is EMC

Comment: A phone charger is typically 5 V x 2 A = 10 W. You're looking for 12 V x 5 A = 60 W so that idea won't work. EMC is ElectroMagnetic Compatibility (avoiding interference with other equipment).

Comment: It will be used in security applications, cameras, intercoms, and many other applications of communication so it wouldn't work then, but aren't any of these options viable for the design

Comment: @AhmedH2O given that you have no experience designing them and no access to ferrite core I think it’s obvious that you’re not going to get far making your own.  May I ask where you’re located that makes procuring transformers impossible?

Comment: In Egypt (comments must be 15 characters)